# Basic question about open and closed sets

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$ and $B$ be open sets in a metric space $X$ and suppose that $B\subseteq \overline{A}$ (where $\overline{A}$ denotes the closure of $A$). Is it true that $B\subseteq A$ ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take $B=(0,2)$ and $A=(0,1)\cup(1,2)$; $\operatorname{cl}A=[0,2]$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $B$ be the entire topological space and let $A$ be a dense open set that isn't the entire space.

Comment: Did you mean $B$ where you typed $A$ and vice versa?

Comment: oh yeah ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2):

**Minimal counterexample**. Take the [Sierpiński space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space). It is the $2$-element set $X = \{0, 1\}$ whose open sets are $\emptyset$, $\{1\}$ and $X$. Now take $A = \{1\}$ and $B = X$. Then $A$ and $B$ are open and $B \subseteq \overline{A}$ (since $\overline{A} = X$), but $B \not\subseteq A$.